# Найти виртуальные COM порты

Tags: delphi, порты, serial

Использую пример из [поста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100798/serial-com-ports-name-or-identification)

Но этот пример не находит виртуальный Com порт. Как его найти? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перебрать файлы с именами COM# как вариант.

Comment: Не знаю правильно ли это. а через SetupDiGetClassDevs возможно это ?

Comment: А как ваш пример должен определить виртуальность порта?

Comment: Пример на который вы ссылаетесь работает как раз через SetupAPI и работает некорректно. Вы, конечно, можете снова попробовать через SetupDiGetClassDevs.

Comment: Вот еще один вариант через реестр: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091084/4712334. Посмотрите предварительно, есть ли в разделе `HKLM\hardware\devicemap\serialcomm` виртуальные com-порты.

Comment: Использовал {A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED} для определения usb портов. вроде нашел. справка  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

На основе части кода из этой статьи [англоязычный форум с примером кода для нахождения СОМ-порта](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22091084/4712334)

, которую любезно предложил пользователь KMV,
сделал такую функцию, которая возвращает ИМЕННО сом-порты (существующие, в том числе и виртуальные) в формате "СОМ1..2" (без всяких "Devices\Serial" и прочего).

```
var
  Form2: TForm2;
  function listComPorts:TStringList;

implementation
//uses Unit1;
{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm2 }



function listComPorts:TStringList;
var
  i: Integer;
  Ports: TStringList;
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Ports := TStringList.Create;
  //with (reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ)) do
  result:=TStringList.Create;
  //result:=[''];
  reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
    with reg do
    try
      reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      if reg.OpenKey('hardware\devicemap\serialcomm', false) then
        try
          ports.BeginUpdate();
          try
            reg.GetValueNames(ports);
            for i := ports.Count -1 downto 0 do
            ports.Strings[i] := reg.ReadString(ports.Strings[i]);
            result:=ports;                  //
            ports.sort()

          finally
            ports.EndUpdate()
          end
        finally
          reg.CloseKey()
        end
      else
        ports.clear()
    finally
    reg.free()
    end

end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   memo1.Lines.Assign(listComPOrts);
   combobox1.Items.Assign(listComPOrts);
end;
```

Немного исправил код чтобы отображалось вертикально.